# Django - nested query to reply on comments

Tags: django, nested

I have the following two models to make it possible that users can answer/reply onto a comment

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


class Comment_Answere(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Creating a reply works like a charm but I don't know how I properly pull all answers/reply's for a specific comment at my template/View

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    list_comments = Comment.objects.get_queryset().filter(post_id=pk).order_by('-published_date')
   # not sure how the comment_answers query has to look like
    comment_answers = Comment_Answere.objects.filter(post_id=pk).order_by('-published_date')
    paginator = Paginator(list_comments, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    comments = paginator.get_page(page)
    args = {
        'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'comment_answers': comment_answers,
    }
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', args)
```

At my template I later than do something like this:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
{% for comment_answer in comment_answers %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Would be awesome if smb. could give me a hint on how I have to stack comments and there reply's together as I currently have all reply's under all comments at my template and that makes no sense at all.

Comment: Why have you got `objects = None` on your models? The `objects` attribute gives your your model manager & allows you to query the database via the ORM.

Comment: Ohh sorry, can be ignored, I just removed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do it like that as 2 queries to create 2 lists in the context.

Your answers relate to a comment, so you could, and probably should, keep that first query;

```py
    list_comments = Comment.objects.get_queryset().filter(post_id=pk).order_by('-published_date')
```

But then take the example to get related answers;

```py
    list_comments.first().comment_answere_set.all()
```

This is how you access the reverse foreign key (related set).

You can also name the reverse relationship so that you don't have to use the default (like I have used above). That would be done using `related_name`;

```py
class Comment_Answere(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(
        Comment,
        related_name='answers',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

If you added this `related_name` the query above would become;

```py
    list_comments.first().answers.all()
```

Some related reading on this is here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Ultimately in your template, when you're iterating over your comments, you then need to check if a comment has the related set. So you would, assuming you had the `related_name`, do something like;

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment.content }}, by {{ comment.author }}
    
    {% for answer in comment.answers.all %}
        {{ answer.content }}, by {{ answer.author }}
    {% empty %}
        No responses
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```